# How can I limit HTML5 video bandwidth usage in Video.js?

Tags: video.js

Trying to roll out a video to a client with limited bandwidth.  The client is concerned that the video will eat up all the bandwidth at their field office.  In testing, I've discovered that even though my video is encoded at 420kbps, when downloading the client it still utilizes about 1.5mbps.  Is there a way to control the maximum bandwidth used by video.js or the video tag?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. The html5 video element doesn't have any throttling options. It's completely up to the browser to decide how to fetch the video data. Some will download the whole thing at once, others will download pieces as you need them. All I think will use as much of the pipe as you give them.

The [media source extensions proposal](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html) hopes to add some ability here, but that won't be available for a while.

I would find somewhere else besides the office to host the video, like Amazon S3.